# Amazon S3 images not loading in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I have a rails application that uploads and displays images from Amazon S3.
I also have an issue displaying some of these images in Chrome!

Take, for example, the following link:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/lafamos-dpk/system/images/2144/thumb/photo_2144.png?1333998967

This just doesn't load in Chrome, but loads just fine in Firefox and Safari.

In a truly mysterious fashion, [this image](http://s3.amazonaws.com/lafamos-dpk/system/main_photos/58/small/artist_58.jpeg?1352941916), which was uploaded through the same system, to the same Amazon S3 bucket, loads just fine [granted, it's a different format, but I'm not sure that matters].

Here's a [link](http://music.lafamos.com/sundaylane) to the page I'm trying to solve these problems on -- the photos under the Press Photos section all the way down at the bottom are just not showing up at all in Chrome.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks!
Yuval

Comment: Both images load fine for me in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43. You sure you haven't got a local caching issue?

Comment: How local are we talking? They still don't open in incognito mode for me, so unless you're talking about local network, then I don't think so. I really don't understand why they're not loading, but the client is the one who reported this issue in the first place -- so I know they're noticing it. Any ideas at all what's going on? Any leads? :) Thanks so much!

Comment: works for me fine in chrome

Comment: @yuval did you find any solution ? in mine case, images from s3 are loading fine in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: I actually haven't tracked down the problem. Interesting you commented on this a couple of days ago -- that's when I was looking into again. I'll post here when I find out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

When you view the site in chrome you're getting a few error's

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://lafamos-dpk.s3.amazonaws.com/system/main_photos/58/small/artist_58.jpg?1291229622
```

.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>system/main_photos/58/small/artist_58.jpg</Key>
<RequestId>1F57BF9D9034CB18</RequestId>
<HostId>
U9HkrMYA6nISFRCt2cQ0Xy89uxkzBnJ2pDmlPz/yiCL4Wb74h9hlIg8eVU46+R7y
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Does the image exist?

Answer (score 0):

Direct links of the images work fine on both Chrome and Firefox, but your `img src` links seem to be broken. I'm getting this in the DevTools console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://flipsidetomusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/album_63.jpg
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. lastError:29
set lastError:29
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. lastError:29
set lastError:29
```

I'd look into resolving that 404 Error. Also, I came across a HackerNews' discussion today that may point to the problem's source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5514344

Apparently Firefox doesn't block non-SSL content on SSL pages by default, but Chrome does. I'd check your S3 bucket permissions, granted, I'm not very familiar with AWS.